# Configuring Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

how to add the Governor in the appropriate spot..they said"Add the following lines in appropriate spot amongst the other govenor's"
Yes, they've given one code that i have to add, but how ?

here is the code:-

```
config CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_SMARTASS
            bool "smartass"
            select CPU_FREQ_GOV_SMARTASS
            select CPU_FREQ_GOV_PERFORMANCE
            help
              Use the CPUFreq governor 'smartass' as default.
```

Comment: I assume this has something to do with building the Linux kernel?

Comment: yes it is...@Otheus

Comment: For the benefit of having your question answered, you should update the title of you question. Something like "configuring Linux kernel: how to add a governor". I have no idea what the answer is, but at least I understand the question. Otherwise, it looks like the entire question is a troll

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your code to the file `drivers/cpufreq/Kconfig` (using the other entries in that file as a guide to the formatting).

You will likely also have to do a few other things (e.g. edit `drivers/cpufreq/Makefile` and add a reference to your governor module source code - see section with comment `# CPUfreq governors`)

Comment: OK, Will try that